# Dell 790 Optiplex Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, operating-systems, dell-optiplex

I am having difficulty installing Windows XP on a Dell 790 Optiplex.  The version of Windows XP I have is a volume licensed version which has SP1 on it.  When I boot from this CD, I get a blue screen of death type of message saying something about the pci.sys being an issue.

Anyone know how I can get Windows XP installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be an issue with the `XP Pro SP1 CD` and `partition size`, I think `SP1` can only work with partitions up to `127GB` in size..
I would slipstream SP3, you can go straight from SP1 to SP3.
Use nLite, it even burns the CD for you.

The only driver needed would be for Sata or Raid, if the Home and Media Centre CD's didn't need a driver slipstreamed in then XP Pro shouldn't either.

Try using a re-writable CD, that will save you using up CD's

Comment: There is a good tutorial here:http://www.zdnet.com/blog/hardware/creating-an-xp-sp3-slipstreamed-iso-file/1848

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this would help you because i manage to install window xp on 11 workstation for opti790

1. Reboot and press F2 to load BIOS page
2. System Configuration -> SATA Opertion -> change to ATA
3. Then Apply.

Reboot and try to reinstall window XP again.

- try at your own risk. =)

Thanks.